# How can I know the actual scale that my Google maps is currently in?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, zooming, scale

I have a Google map (v3) on my site and I want to know what scale is my current zoom. The thing is that the user can change it's zoom so the scale can change.

The information I need is the actual width in kilometers of my map. I know I can use Bounds... but is there any other way? I really don't want to use Bounds.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok. I decided to use Bounds :P. Anyway, Is there a way to get the actual scale?

Comment: With the mercator projection scale changes with latitude, so this isn't as simple as it sounds.

Comment: You are right. But I don't understand why Google provides an scale graphic that you can add to your map if you want. So it looks like google can tell you the real scale of your map.

Answer (score 3):

So you can call map.getBounds().  Then you can use functions on the [google.maps.geometry.spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#spherical) class like `computeDistanceBetween` or `computeLength`.  Something like this I think should give you what you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.476706,0); // London

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: homeLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {           
            // find out the map's bounds:
            var bounds = map.getBounds();

            // from that, get the coordinates for the NE and SW corners
            var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
            var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();

            // from that, figure out the latitudes and the longitudes
            var lat1 =  NE.lat();
            var lat2 =  SW.lat();

            var lng1 =  NE.lng();
            var lng2 =  SW.lng();

            // construct new LatLngs using the coordinates for the horizontal distance between lng1 and lng2
            var horizontalLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lng1);
            var horizontalLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lng2);

            // construct new LatLngs using the coordinates for the vertical distance between lat1 and lat2
            var verticalLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lng1);
            var verticalLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2,lng1);

            // work out the distance horizontally
            var horizontal = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(horizontalLatLng1,horizontalLatLng2);

            // work out the distance vertically
            var vertical = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(verticalLatLng1,verticalLatLng2);

            // round to kilometres to 1dp
            var horizontalkm = convertMetresToKm(horizontal);
            var verticalkm = convertMetresToKm(vertical);

            alert(horizontalkm + ' km horizontal, ' + verticalkm + ' km vertical');
        });
    }

    function convertMetresToKm(metres) {
        return Math.round(metres / 1000 *10)/10;    // distance in km rounded to 1dp
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm appreciate for your reply.I'm new to google maps api v3,and i still do not know how to get scale by map's south-west and north-east corners.

Comment: Thank you,but it semms to be no works.I want to get the scale value from the scaleControl,such as 1km/2000ft,200m/1000ft.Sorry,i do not have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, nor how to get it.  I just saw "The information I need is the actual width in kilometers of my map,such as 50km."  which is what the above code does.

Comment: See also my article here where I expand on the idea of displaying the size of the map: http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/google-maps-size/