# How can I know the scale that my Google maps is currently in?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know there is a [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092788/how-can-i-know-the-actual-scale-that-my-google-maps-is-currently-in), but no answers.

I want to know what scale is my current google map.The information I need is the actual width in kilometers of my map,such as 50km.

Some one says that scale can be calculated by Bounds,how to?
And is there any other way?

Thank you very much!